# Parsing object of objects

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I'd like to set `#currentWord` span to the hovered over Chinese word's English translation.

To do that, I'm storing words based on their category in an object:

```
var vocab = {
"pronouns" :
{
    'wǒ'    : 'I',
    'nǐ'    : 'You',
},
"nouns" : 
{
    'gǒu'   : 'dog'
},
"verbs" : 
{
    'bāng'  : 'help',
    'xún'   : 'search',
}
```

};

I then call `parseHoveredText` to send the word to the `currentWord` span:

```
$("#currentWord").text(parseHoveredText(word));
```

parseHoveredText() Function:

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
  for (obj in vocab) {
      log(vocab[obj][word]);
      return vocab[obj][word];
  }
  return "";
};
```

When I hover over "Ni", it correctly outputs the English "You"

[image]

Console output is also correct: `You`

---

**However:** Hovering over `bang` (in the "verbs" object) outputs nothing:

[image]

Console output shows: `Undefined`

**The weird thing is:** If I comment out `//return vocab[obj][word];`, the console outputs the correct associated English, "Help", but still doesn't display it to the `span`...

Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: @Sergio it's a different question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are iterating over the whole `vocab` object and returning in the first iteration without even checking whether the word is in the inner object.

Hovering over "Ni" works "by chance" since it seems that the property in the first iteration is `nouns`. But since "bang" is not in `vocab.nouns`, you get `undefined`.

You have to check whether the word is contained in each category and return the translation when you found it.

```
for (obj in vocab) {
    if (word in vocab[obj]) {
        return vocab[obj][word];
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, since my incoming dialog text might be capital (`Nǐ`) or lower case (`nǐ`), and that my vocab object only has lower case `nǐ`, I wanted to make sure all cases were checked... So I'm doing `if (word in vocab[obj] || word.toLowerCase() in vocab[obj]) {` but it's not working... Why?

Comment: I cannot say, it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/CbKzh/. Maybe you want to try `word.toLocaleLowerCase()` instead.

Comment: Hmm this also did not work... `log(word + ", " + word.toLowerCase() + ", " + vocab[obj][word]);` outputs `Nǐ, nǐ, undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the element exists in the current part of speech before returning:

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
  for (obj in vocab) {
    if (vocab[obj][word]) {
      log(vocab[obj][word]);
      return vocab[obj][word];
    }
  }
  return "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "if" statement. You code loop through vocab obj but on first step call return and out. If you comment return function will loop through all vocab but will return ""

```
function parseHoveredText (word) {
  for (obj in vocab) {
     var result = log(vocab[obj][word]);
     if(result)
     {
        log(result);
        return result;
     }
  }
 return "";
};
```